# How to download a file using Selenium on a Flask app?

Tags: python, selenium, flask

I've built a simple app that logs in to a website and downloads a file after a few clicks. When run on my local machine the file downloads fine with no issues, but with the Flask deployment the file doesn't get saved anywhere.

The Python script works a bit like this:

```
def download_file(url, username, password):
    with webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=os.environ.get('CHROMEDRIVER_PATH'), chrome_options=chrome_options) as driver:
        driver.get(url)

        # Code that logs in to the interface
        # Code that goes to the relevant page and apply filters

        export = driver.find_element_by_xpath("Export_XPATH")
        export.click()
        print("[*] Exported file")
```

And in my `app.py`:

```
@app.route("/download", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def download():
    if request.method == "POST":
        return Response(
            download_file(URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD),
            mimetype='text/csv',
            headers={"Content-disposition": f"attachment; filename=report_raw.csv"}
            )
    return render_template('download.html')
```

The HTML is trivial but I'll attach it below anyway:

```
download.html
<form action="", method="post">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center">
            <input type="submit" value="Download Data" class="input-group-text">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Right now it just downloads an empty csv - probably because the `download_file()` function doesn't return the file, but downloads it from the last `.click()`.

Here's a few things that I've tried:

1. Define a specific save directory by using `chrome_options.add_experimental_option()` - the Flask logs show that even though the directory is correct, the file is nowhere to be found. Something about ephemeral storage that I can't wrap my head around...
2. Use the `requests` library to get the response by finding the download endpoint + copying in headers and using the `drivers.get_cookies()` method for cookies. Got the error `CONNECTION ERROR: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response',))`

I'm very new to programming and open to any and all suggestions! My constraints are that if possible, I'd prefer not to use a storage solution like S3 (but if this is the only option, I'd like to know that too).